# blank page with my custom region - drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i have add my region to a info file:

```
regions[mine] = Mine
```

then i have created a view with a block display and I add this block to my custom region.

Last, I invoke in my node.tpl.php with:

```
print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('mine'));
```

but I have a blank page with html:

Please any help??!!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you invoking that in your node.tpl.php file? This doesn't make any sense in the context. It appears that you want to have a block inside of a region - this is configured in the administration pages, not theme files.

If you are getting a totally blank html page rendered then you likely have an error in your PHP somewhere - Drupal has a habit of swallowing PHP errors without any visible warnings.